# Java notify function weird behavior

Tags: java, android, qt

I have an app that I am building in Qt and I am implementing Java aswell so that I am able to use the Google-Play-Services.

I took this function from the Qt Notifier example but it seems that the function throws an error or something as soon as it calls the java API's.

Qt doesn't show any errors so I added print statements after every line to see where it goes wrong and as soon as a Java library gets called, the function stops.

this is the function:

```
public static void notify(String s)
{
    System.out.println(s);

    if (m_notificationManager == null) {
        System.out.println("1111");
        m_notificationManager = (NotificationManager)m_instance.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        System.out.println("2222");
        m_builder = new Notification.Builder(m_instance);
        System.out.println("3333");
        m_builder.setContentTitle("A message from Qt!");
        System.out.println("4444");
    }

    System.out.println("5555");
    m_builder.setContentText(s);
    System.out.println("6666");
    m_notificationManager.notify(1, m_builder.build());
    System.out.println("7777");
}
```

and the output is:

```
I/System.out(25125): test string
I/System.out(25125): 1111
```

(s = test string)

I have also gone through the Notification example's directories and the AndroidManifest. But I think the libraries should be able to import fine as I have referenced the google-play-API to my project with the Android commandline tool provided by the Android-SDK.

**So my question is: What could I have done wrong?**

and for completeness sake, here is the code of the .java file:

```
package org.qtproject.qt5.example;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;

public class NotificationClient extends org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity
{
    private static NotificationManager m_notificationManager;
    private static Notification.Builder m_builder;
    private static NotificationClient m_instance;

    public NotificationClient()
    {
        System.out.println("it works2222");
        m_instance = this;
    }

    public static void notify(String s)
    {
        System.out.println(s);

        if (m_notificationManager == null) {
            System.out.println("1111");
            m_notificationManager = (NotificationManager)m_instance.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            System.out.println("2222");
            m_builder = new Notification.Builder(m_instance);
            System.out.println("3333");
            m_builder.setContentTitle("A message from Qt!");
            System.out.println("4444");
        }

        System.out.println("5555");
        m_builder.setContentText(s);
        System.out.println("6666");
        m_notificationManager.notify(1, m_builder.build());
        System.out.println("7777");
    }
}
```

Comment: Any stack trace? Is there any chance `m_instance` is `null` before printing `"2222"`? Use a debugger?

Comment: @mena          Using a debugger in Qt doesn't seem to work as the breakpoints i set don't get activated at all when i debug it, thats why I decided to use the println statements to see where it goes wrong. You are probably right about the m_instance being null though. Also I am trying to figure out right now how to print a stacktrace. I just started with the implementation of Java into Qt so its all quite new to me still.

Comment: Definitely not a QT expert here, but shouldn't you get LogCat like in every other instance?

Comment: @Mena          never heard of LogCat, it would be nice to have a log of all the things that happen. I will see if I can implement it.

Comment: [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)'s some docs. Should come bundled with your IDE too, e.g. the Eclipse-based one.

Comment: @Mena          thnx, I will check it out shortly

Answer (score 0):

A nullptr Exception was thrown. I caught it with:

```
    public static void notify(String s)
    {
        try {
            if (m_notificationManager == null) {
                m_notificationManager = (NotificationManager)m_instance.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                m_builder = new Notification.Builder(m_instance);
                m_builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
                m_builder.setContentTitle("A message from Qt!");
            }

            m_builder.setContentText(s);
            m_notificationManager.notify(1, m_builder.build());
        } catch(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: And were you able to fix this issue? I am seeing the same thing. Running the notification example works fine, but adding to my project fails. My error output:
W System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.app.Activity.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
?

Comment: I do remember that I fixed it. I was able to produce a notification but it was quite a long time ago.

Comment: If it help get the grey-matter working, I keep getting an error pointing to m_instance being null...

Comment: @SamGrant Well, if the m_instance is null, that means that something went wrong with extending the android Activity through Qt. Or did you maybe forget to initialize m_instance? In my constructor, i call: "m_instance = this;"

Comment: Yep. Using the same code as in the example:

    public NotificationClient()
    {
        m_instance = this;
    }

Comment: No other ideas?

Comment: @SamGrant.     not sure.. it seems like something wasn't configured right in your setup. Is your constructor even called?

Comment: I'll double check... but I assume so, since I'm using the default setup.

Comment: @SamGrant  maybe just try getSystemService instead of mInstance.getSystemService

Comment: Good idea, Will do.

Comment: @SamGrant Any progress?

Comment: Not yet... trying it this week.